# Unable to iterate list of blobs in python variable

Tags: python, azure, iteration, azure-blob-storage

I am fetching the output 'file_list' from blob_list

```
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
    for blob in blob_listL
    file_list = f"Name: {blob.name},"
```

Now when I print file_list, i getting below output.

```
    file_list = [
            "Name: a/abc/log1.parquet",
            "Name: c/abc/employee/log1.parquet",
            "Name: d/abc/employee/log1.parquet",
            "Name: g/abc/log1.parquet"
        ]
```

After that i want to iterate to list of files from certain directory path

```
    files_in_d_employee = []

    for file_path in file_list:
        if 'd/abc/employee' in file_path:
            files_in_d_employee.append(file_path)
            print(files_in_d_employee)
```

And i am getting below output,

```
['N']

['N', 'a']

['N', 'a', 'm']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', ':']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', ':', 'd']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', ':', 'd', '/']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', ':', 'd', '/', 'a']

['N', 'a', 'm', 'e', ':', 'd', '/', 'a', 'b']
```

Desired Output:

```
Name: d/abc/employee/log1.parquet
```

Comment: You have two times file_list set: file_list = f"Name: {blob.name},"

Answer (score 1):

> Name: d/abc/employee/log1.parquet

To obtain the desired output by iterating through a list of blobs in a Python variable, you can use the following code:

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("xxxxx")
container_client = client.get_container_client("sample")

blob_list = container_client.list_blobs()
files_in_d_employee = []

for blob in blob_list:
    file_path = blob.name
    file_list = f"Name: {file_path}"
    print(file_list)
    
    if 'd/abc/employee' in file_path:
        files_in_d_employee.append(file_path)
print(files_in_d_employee)
```

The code above retrieves a list of blobs in a container named **`sample`**. It then iterates through the list of blobs and prints the name of each file. If the file path contains **`d/abc/employee`**, it adds the file path to a list called **`files_in_d_employee`**. Finally, it prints the list of file paths that contain **`d/abc/employee`**.

**Output:**

```
Name: a/abc/05-03-2024.html
Name: c/abc/employee/temp.png
Name: d/abc/employee/mountainview.png
Name: g/abc/bike.png
['d/abc/employee/mountainview.png']
```

[image]